# Rollbar impact on rails performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rollbar

Does rollbar impact a rails application performance? 
From development and quality perspectives, it's a very useful. But I worry about production performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rollbar will have a varying impact on application performance depending on how you configure it and how often your application is reporting errors.

By default, Rollbar sends error data *synchronously*, and the typical response time from the API will be 10s to low 100s of milliseconds.

To minimize performance impact, you can configure Rollbar to send data *asynchronously* using one of the following options:

### girl_friday

Add the following in `config/initializers/rollbar.rb`:

```
config.use_async = true
```

Asynchronous reporting falls back to Threading if girl_friday is not installed.

### sucker_punch

Add the following in `config/initializers/rollbar.rb`:

```
config.use_sucker_punch
```

### Sidekiq

Add the following in config/initializers/rollbar.rb:

```
config.use_sidekiq
```

The default Sidekiq queue will be `rollbar` but you can also supply custom Sidekiq options:

```
config.use_sidekiq 'queue' => 'default'
```

You also need to add the name of the queue to your sidekiq.yml

```
:queues:
- default
- rollbar
```

Start the redis server:

```
$ redis-server
```

Start Sidekiq from the root directory of your Rails app and declare the name of your queue. Unless you've configured otherwise, the queue name is `rollbar`:

```
$ bundle exec sidekiq -q rollbar
```

For every error job a new report will be sent to Rollbar API, also for error retried jobs. You can configure the retries threshold to start reporting to rollbar:

```
config.sidekiq_threshold = 3 # Start reporting from 3 retries jobs
```

### Resque

Add the following in `config/initializers/rollbar.rb`:

```
config.use_resque
```

You can also supply a custom Resque queue:

```
config.use_resque :queue => 'my_queue'
```

Now you can just start a new Resque worker processing jobs in that queue:

```
$ QUEUE=my_queue bundle exec resque:work
```

### DelayedJob

Add the following in `config/initializers/rollbar.rb`:

```
config.use_delayed_job
```

### Threading

Add the following in `config/initializers/rollbar.rb`:

```
config.use_thread
```

Full details of available options are in the [rollbar-gem docs](https://rollbar.com/docs/notifier/rollbar-gem/#asynchronous-reporting).